# passing url param to backing bean method

Tags: jsf-2

I have the following code in my Facelet:

```
<ui:composition template="/templates/mastertemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="pageTitle">
        <h:outputFormat value="#{msgs.productPageTitle}">
            <f:param value="#{param.productName}"/>
        </h:outputFormat>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:param name="categoryName" value="#{param.categoryName}"/>

    <ui:define name="content">
        <p>#{param.productName}</p>
        <h:form>
            <h:commandLink action="#{cartBean.addItemToCart(param.productName)}">
                <f:ajax event="action" render=":cart :cartPrice" />
                <h:graphicImage value="resources/img/addToCart.gif"/>
            </h:commandLink>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

It prints the `#{param.productName}` as it should. The `cartBean` expects a `String` as argument for its `addItemToCart` method (I know this is terrible, but not my choice). I have set up a logger in my `cartBean` and it tells me that the parameter is not coming through, it is empty.

If I do the following:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{cartBean.addItemToCart('someProductName')}">
    <f:ajax event="action" render=":cart :cartPrice" />
    <h:graphicImage value="resources/img/addToCart.gif"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

I substitute the `#{param.productName}` for a string literal, it works fine. Why can't I pass the param value as argument? I get an `EvaluationException` which explains why my logger sees an empty string but I don't understand how I should do this then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's possible that way but at the very least it seems to be bad practice. You'd insert the string to your backing back without any validation/conversion options.

I found a tutorial which explains what you should do to make it work [here](http://balusc.blogspot.be/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters).